# Python patch context manager to return object

Tags: python, mocking, contextmanager

I am trying to patch a context manager that does a database lookup and returns an object like follows:

```
class MyClass:
    @contextlib.contextmanager
    def client_ctx(self, id):
         # hidrate from DB and yield object
         yield client # instance of SQAlchemy model Client

    def run(self, id):
        with self.client_ctx(id) as cl:
            # do work here
```

Client class in this case is a SQLAlchemy model.

In my tests I am trying to patch this method `client_ctx` to simply return an object instantiated in the tests like this:

```
@patch('MyClass.client_ctx')
def test_ctx(self, _mocked_ctx_manager):
    myclass = MyClass()

    client = Client(
        id=1,
        code='test-client')

    _mocked_ctx_manager.__enter__.return_value = client
    myclass.run(1)
```

I'm getting: `TypeError: Object of type MagicMock is not JSON serializable` which makes no sense to me. What am I doing wrong, is there a better way to mock a context manager ?

Comment: Take a look at stdlib [`mock_open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
_mocked_ctx_manager.return_value.__enter__.return_value = client
```

Your `_mocked_ctx_manager` returns a context manager. Therefore you need to set the `__enter__.return_value` of `_mocked_ctx_manager.return_value`.

I found the following article to be helpful: [Surrender Python Mocking! I Have You Now.](https://medium.com/python-pandemonium/surrender-python-mocking-i-have-you-now-5805e91cfbf4)